# How to change Windows 11 default font without breaking Windows search

Tags: windows, windows-11, fonts

Upgraded one of my PCs from Windows 10 to 11 (23H2 22631.2861).

After the migration, I noticed that the search feature did not work anymore :

- Nothing happens when I click on the search icon on the task bar
- Weird start menu UI freeze when I click on the search bar in the start menu panel

I tried many candidate solutions ("sfc /scannow", "dism ...", restarts, Windows updates, many PowerShell scripts, rebuilt the search index, etc). Nothing worked.

I finally found out the cause. It simply comes from an age-old and quite known custom regedit file that we can use to replace the "system Windows font" (the one used in explorer windows), for example described in https://www.lifewire.com/change-font-windows-11-6827640. I used Tahoma font, but it should not be relevant.

I've been using this for years, over several Windows versions. But both my Windows 11 PC do not like it. I found some references to this issue:

- https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/type-here-to-search-crashes-if-you-change-windows/2421db4a-b9de-43cf-93e5-f27bea288c26
- https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-11-search-bar-broken-after-using-new-font/f7127fb9-11bb-4e20-b4c2-9a94f88ea27d
- https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows11/comments/tw0a6q/cant_open_windows_search_in_the_taskbar_after/

So, how can I change my Windows font without breaking the Windows search?

Comment: In Settings, look for Font Settings and changing to one of these does not seem to break Search.

Comment: There is no such option.

Comment: In newer Windows 10 and all of Windows 11 there is no option for default fonts

Comment: See here: https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-11-customize-fonts/

Comment: Does not work. As described in the question, this breaks the Windows search panels.

Answer (score 1):

> ".... known custom regedit file that we can use to replace the
> "Windows font"

Windows 11 is not Windows 10 or earlier.
Also, 95 times out of 100, you do not need to use the registry to run Windows.

Use Settings, Personalization, Font Settings to change fonts and Windows Search does not break.

[image: Change Windows 11 Fonts]

To fix your Windows System now, you will probably have to do a Windows 10 Repair Install.

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything.

If Repair Install fails to fix the issue, back up and install Windows fresh.

Comment: How you installed font change fairly late in Windows 10 lifecycle and what was possible before that change most definitely isn’t supported on Windows 11 which was built upon those later builds of Windows 10.

Comment: I have not used Windows 10 for a half dozen years but the steps I outlined work in Windows 10 and 11. (verified)

Comment: I was explaining the reason the registry method might have worked and suddenly stopped working between Windows 10 and Windows 11

Comment: I stay away from registry hacking to ensure long term good operation

Comment: I don't remember adding or removing fonts to Windows. Also AFAIK, Tahoma is one of the fonts that come with Windows.


Yes, I'd rather stay away from registry hacks, but all anwsers to "how do I change the windows 11 font" point to that hack.


Now, in "Settings / Personalisation / Fonts" I see that I can add or remove fonts but not where I can use one of them as the "system font" or "default font" (the one used by explorer windows). Am I missing something here ?

Comment: The registry change no longer works, and so far as I know for later Windows 10 and now 11, the fonts in Personalization are all that is available. I checked File Explorer as well.

Comment: I still do not understand how you can change the default font from the Personalization section of the Settings. Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: I am fairly sure so-called default font or system font is what Microsoft has established.  At this point, I have not found a way to change them.  I am on Windows 11.  Font settings in Control Panel no longer change things either. That is the direction Microsoft is taking.  My note about Repair was to fix Search

Comment: I finally ended up repairing the Windows 11 installation. It did fix the Search issue and reverted to the default font. I actually think it fixed the issue BECAUSE it reverted to the defaut font. No solution to my issue then.